# Change back from text() to original text

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to change text on a clicked element.
But how do I change the text back to the original text?

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
        $(this).text("You clicked me!");
    });
```

I want to be able to click on `.myClass` again and get the original text...is there something comparable to "toggle" with `text()`?

Comment: You can either store the original text, or show/hide two blocks of text. There's no built-in function to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an extension to solve this very problem.  It's only a few lines:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function(stateOne, stateTwo) {
        return this.each(function() {
            stateTwo = stateTwo || '';
            $(this).text() !== stateTwo && stateOne ? $(this).text(stateTwo) : $(this).text(stateOne);
        });  
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleText('show', 'hide'); //Toggles from hide to show
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the original text in a variable, then toggle between them.

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the text of the field, the original text is gone. You need to store that value somewhere. A hidden field could work, or a variable. Depends on when you want to switch back to the original text.